# My styles aren't being rendered by the browser. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have enqueue a stylesheet into a plugin I built. When I load the page I can see that there is a link tag created linking to my stylesheet. I can view the stylesheet in chrome's `source` tab. However the class is not applied to my element.

[My Element without it's class being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv83m.png)

[Header showing the link to my style sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcdVd.png)

[Source tab showing the stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE7AM.png)

I've added this line to the top of my file to make sure that the stylesheet is enqueued before the subsequent html is rendered

```
<?php echo wp_style_is($this->product_controller->plugin_name) ? 'enqueued' : 'nope'; ?>
```

this always echos out 'enqueued'

when my class is instantiated this function runs. This calls the function on whatever controller is passed in.

```
private function add_default_actions($controller, $classname)
{
    $prefixed_name = "pp_" . $classname;
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $controller, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $controller, 'enqueue_scripts' );
    //when a request is made to to admin-ajax.php
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $prefixed_name, $controller, 'ajax_handler');
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $prefixed_name, $controller, 'check_nonce');
}
```

this is the function that gets run in my $controller

```
public function enqueue_styles()
{
    $location = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/'. $this->classname .'.css';
    wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_name, $location, array(), $this->version, 'all' );
}
```

I'm trying to turn a `h2` tag blue so that I know my styles is getting rendered and my browser is like, nope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was calling it `classname` instead of `class`. That fixed it.

I've been working in javascript too long.